# Delete Dropdown values using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation here,

Using JQuery I'm appending some values in drop down list.. Even it is one or two value that appended in drop down list..

**For Add,**

```
tableui+='<option value="">'+resourceadd+'</option>';
$('#resourcess').append(tableui);
```

When the page reloads automatically the value stored in db.

For example 4 values added in dropdown list **(Values are not stored in db)**, I want to delete last value. I'm using,

```
$("#resourcess :last-child").remove();
```

The same condition, I want to delete middle of two values, How to do it??

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know the value of the `option` you want to remove, you could use `filter`:

```
$('#resources option').filter(function() {
    return this.value == 'foo'; // insert your value here.
}).remove();
```

Or an attribute selector:

```
$('#resources option[value="foo"]').remove();
```

If you don't know the value, but do know the position of the `option` within the select, you could remove it by index using `eq()`:

```
$('#resources option').eq(1).remove(); // remove the 2nd option
```

Comment: In the place of value I'm not getting any values..  I used dynamically to delete values using,, $("#resourcess option[value="+delid+"]").remove();,, But I couldnt delete.. How can i get value in Option????

Comment: That should work fine. What is the value of `delid`, does it match the value of any option? Any errors in the console?

Comment: In the hidden text field I'm assigning `delid` to dynamic deletion ,, I'm iterating `delid` in while loop. But I couldn't it any option value in `delid`...